# sequencia de letras e pontos em c

Tags: c

Preciso fazer um programa que compare várias strings, eu já tentei fazer um `switch` mas não deu certo porque só aceita um caractere de comparação. Eu preciso que cada ponto represente uma letra, exemplo:

```
a .
b ..
c ...
d ... .
```

Isso foi o que eu consegui fazer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main () {
    char letra;
    printf("Digite os pontos:");
    scanf("%s",&letra);
    switch (letra){
    
        case '..':
            printf("a\n");
        break;
        
        case '..':
            printf("b\n");
        break;
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira de você implementar isso é:

1 - Obter a string com os pontos (seu código já está errado porque coloca em um char onde cabe apenas um '.');

2 - printf("Letra: %c", strlen(string_com_pontos) + 0x60);

Com essa simples linha de printf você transforma x pontos '.' em um correspondente ASCII minúsculo. Obviamente que precisa colocar proteções para o máximo de pontos e nenhum, mas é bem tranquilo.